# Tell the best practice for injecting secrets values to CloudRun

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

I deploy cloud run with cloud build.
Following is cloudbuild.yaml and deploy command.

```sh
$ cat cloudbuid.yaml
steps:
  - id: Cloud Run Deploy
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: [
      run, deploy, $_SERVICE_NAME, --allow-unauthenticated,
      --image, $_IMAGE_NAME,
      --region, us-central1,
      --platform, managed,
      --set-env-vars,
      "DB_USER=$_DB_USER,
      DB_PASSWORD=$_DB_PASSWORD,
      DB_DATABASE=$_DB_DATABASE,
      DB_HOST=$_DB_CONNECTION_NAME,
      DB_ONCLOUD=$_DB_ONCLOUD,
      SLACK_CLIENT_ID=$_SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
      SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET=$_SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN=$_SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=$_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY",
      --max-instances, '1000',
      --set-cloudsql-instances, $_DB_CONNECTION_NAME,
      --service-account, my-service-account-email
    ]
# deploy

$ gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml \
    --substitutions=_SERVICE_NAME=my-application,_IMAGE_NAME=my-image,_DB_USER=$DB_USER,_DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD,_DB_DATABASE=$DB_DATABASE,_DB_CONNECTION_NAME=$DB_CONNECTION_NAME,_SLACK_CLIENT_ID=$SLACK_CLIENT_ID,_SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET=$SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,_SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN=$SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN,_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=$GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,_DB_ONCLOUD=$DB_ONCLOUD
```

As you can see, the secrets(ex. DB_PASSWORD,SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN,...etc) is specified from environment variables via the substitute option.

However, in this case, pure secrets will be exposed in the CloudRun management screen of the GCP console.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I think these secrets should be shown by nobody.
What is the best practice to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the new Google [Cloud service for secret management](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/). Only reference your secrets in the env var and perform a query to the secret manager for getting the secret content.

Comment: Do you know document which is written about using secret management at cloudbuild.yaml. I couldn't found that on GCP document.

Comment: Can you describe what do you want to achieve in Cloud Build? I can share a POC with you if you want, I just want to be sure that is relevant before working on it!

Comment: When deploy Cloud Run, I want to inject environment variables to docker container with Cloud Build. The Environment variables are secrets information.

Comment: So, you want to get the secret in Cloud Build, and set the values in clear in environment variable? Am I right?

Comment: What does setting a value in clear mean?
I expect that the Cloud Run application can reference the decrypted value.

Comment: So, you might be right.

Comment: If you set the decrypted value in the Cloud Run environment variable, the value are in clear (I mean plain text) in the configuration/GUI/`gcloud run services describe`/YAML. The best way is to set the reference of Secret manager into the Cloud Run env variable, and to decrypt the value at runtime into your Cloud Run app.